# How can I track the number of times an image is accessed on my Microsoft server?

Tags: html, http, iis, server, logfile

Say I have an image on my server

```
C:\inetpub\somesite\images\someimage.jpg
```

whose URL is

```
http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/images/someimage.jpg
```

and which I'm using in the HTML

```
<img src="http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/images/someimage.jpg"/>
```

of an HTML email I'm sending out. I want to see how many people read this email by tracking how many times a request is made to use that image. Is that possible? Is there a better way of doing this without using 3rd-party software? I know about `LogFile`, but I don't want to have to develop a script that looks through every text document for the number of instances of the expression `"someimage.jpg"`, although that's what I might have to do.

Comment: What technologies are you willing to try?  Is this a one-time query or will you do this often?  Have you considered installing a web statistics package?

Comment: I will do this about once every day

Comment: You answered 1 of 3 questions.  Keep going.